# Git serve different branches on server

Tags: git, server, webserver

I thought about some advanced A/B testing on a webserver and I was hoping I could easily implement this using git.

---

### Simple example

Let me explain myself further with a simple example, let's say I have the following 3 branches:

- master
- blue-button
- red-button

These branches contain all a HTML file, the difference is obvious in the button color.

Normally the master branch would have been served to the visitor, however I would like to test on say 10% of the visitors the other branches to see which branch gives the best conversion rate (clicking the button).

This will require some script which will divide users in groups, and then serve the right branch to this user.

---

### Scope of the question

The project I'm working on:

- runs on PHP > 5.5 and it is possible to extends it with Java code.
- (currently) consists of 2.84 Gigabyte storage excluding composer dependencies, cache and database storage
- should be able to serve up to 100 experiments at the same time
- preferably, older experiments should be able to be served as well if needed

Any experiment must be able to have any alternative file(s) in the git branch. A/B testing in this case is not limited to the user interface, but it should (among other things) also support different:

- content (which will requires db and cache modifications)
- fundamental code (for testing speed differences)
- *more will follow*

Some of those points will require changes in underlying frameworks, the way they are used or other files. Therefor it must be possible to change any file in a branch.

---

Now I'd like to know which options I have to let the server access all branches at the same time.

Options I thought of:

- switch branch (checkout) on every request, will obviously be slow
- clone each branch into a sub folder, which will duplicate files

I was hoping there was a more robust solution for this problem:

- Which does not duplicate files.
- Which is fast. Optimally, it should be as fast as accessing any ordinary file.
- Which has a programmatic approach preferably in Java or PHP

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Git's the wrong tool for this.  Dynamic content is what webservers do..

Comment: @jthill You misunderstand the point. Each git branch contains a dynamic web server.

Comment: You are describing an A/B testing setup for your website. I invite you to look up `A/B testing setup [language]` to find relevant informations on how to set up your code and your server for such a mechanism to work.

Comment: @LeGEC Thank you for your comment. However, I'm not looking for a testing setup specifically. This question is more about how to use git branches as scenarios in a programmatic and efficient way (time and space).

Comment: @Time : you seem to focus on space usage. How much space is taken by one checkout (the extracted files, without the `.git` directory) ?

Comment: @LeGEC The project is large (talking Gigabytes). The system should be able to serve a lot of different experiments, say 100 at a time. Preferably, experiments which have been ended, should still be able to be examined. Therefor I'd not like to duplicate files. Most experiments change no more than a few files. But they must be able to change **every** file.

Comment: @Tim : I think I do not understand the scope of your task. I thought it was about presenting 2 or 3 predefined different interfaces on a website depending on the client, then storing data (e.g : in google analytics) to compare some end results. Could you update your question to better describe your needs ? What is the scope of what you call "an experiment" ?

Comment: @LeGEC I've added a scope. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105570/discussion-between-legec-and-tim).

Comment: @Tim : what *is* included in your 2.84 G of data ? code ? images ? binaries ? videos ? something else ?

Comment: @LeGEC Mostly code (libraries, a lot of views, scripts and styles) and images. Also images need to be able to be taken part of experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your schema with smart deploy system. You need these steps:

- clone each 3 branches (master, blue and red) to separate folders
- master branch is canonical and we don't touch it
- go into blue branch and compare files into root directory with files into root directory of master branch. If hashes of files is equal then you replace "blue" file with hard link to "master" file (maybe symbolic link, it's question of performance). Recursively go ahead with files into nested directories.
- go into red branch and repeat the same actions as for blue branch

You can implement such deploy strategy with [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) and custom task on Ruby language.

I add explanatory drawing
[image]

**UPDATED ALGORITHM:**

This approach is more complicated but we don't clone 3 branches:

- clone master branch and create folders for blue and red versions
- master branch is canonical and we don't touch it
- go into blue version folder
- get changed files with command `git diff --name-status blue..master`

assume we get this output of diff command

```
A       test_added.txt
D       test_deleted.txt
M       text_modified.txt
D       test/test.txt
```

- so we can create links for every file/folder which not mentioned in output of diff command
- if file marked with `A` or `M` letter (e.g. `test_added.txt`, `text_modified.txt`) we should run `git cat-file blob blue:test_added.txt > test_added.txt`
- if file marked with `D` (e.g. `test_deleted.txt`) we should ignore this file
- for nested foldres (e.g. `test/`) we need to recursively go ahead with above steps
- go into red version folder and repeat the same actions as for blue one

Comment: I like this approach. I will wait for some other answer, otherwise this will definitely be accepted.

Comment: The downside of this approach is, that it will duplicate files for the time being. With a large project this method will be time consuming. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I've updated algorithm with coning only master branch and process other branches with commands like `git diff` and `git cat-file blob`